# 3-way switch with 2 lights, alternate off/on

Tags: electrical

I have (2) 3-way switches on stairs & 2 lights, one @ the bottom & 2nd one @ the top. Each switch up turns on 1 light & off 2nd light, down turns on 2nd light & off 1st light

Comment: You do understand *there will be no way to turn the light off*?  (come to think of it, that might be nice for full-on vs. "nightlight mode", I've got that in a fluorescent troffer, put 3 watts of LED that's on 24x7, but I don't switch it, it's hardwired on.)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Has it always been like this or just since you rewired it?  Sounds like a traveler and load switched but one light on and one light off  is weird..

Comment: Sorry, new construction & i did wiring. I can't seem to get them synched. I tried changing the traveler & now have a new problem. Bottom switch has to be on for upper switch to work (on & off). If bootom sw. is off, upper sw. won't work

Comment: Right of the bat there are **two travelers** needed besides all other wires.    Can you diagram out how this thing is wired?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Neither your question nor your answer are clear; would you edit and clarify them? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Perfectly clear to me, got it fixed thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got off track when i read about the screw colors on the switch corresponding to colors of wires. According to the diagram, I had it correct, but I changed the hot wire to the black screw and the traveler to the brass screw and it works perfectly! Thank you all for your help